# Why would MySQL break wget_iri_relative_to_abs?

Tags: mysql, c, wget

Consider the following reproducer:

```
#include <wget.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mysql.h>

MYSQL *mysql_con;

void
mysql_stop()
{
        mysql_close(mysql_con);
}

void
mysql_start()
{
        mysql_con = mysql_init(NULL);
        if (mysql_con == NULL)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(mysql_con));
                exit(1);
        }
        if (mysql_real_connect(mysql_con, "localhost", "crawler", "password", "crawl", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(mysql_con));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}

const char * parseURI (char *base_url, char *url)
{
    wget_iri *base = wget_iri_parse(base_url, NULL);
    wget_buffer *buf = wget_buffer_alloc(8192);
    const char *uri = wget_iri_relative_to_abs(base, url, strlen(url), buf);
    wget_buffer_free(&buf);
    wget_iri_free(&base);
    return uri;
}

void crawler_init()
{
    const char *url2 = parseURI("http://www.google.com/", "/intl/en/policies/privacy/");
    printf("%s\n", url2);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *url2 = parseURI("http://www.google.com/", "/intl/en/policies/privacy/");
    printf("%s\n", url2);
    mysql_start();
    crawler_init();
    mysql_stop();
}
```

The output from running this program is:

```
http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/
��7�
```

The first printf in main is printing out the absolute url as expected.
The second printf in crawler_init is printing out garbage instead of the same absolute url.

This appears to be related to `mysql_real_connect` as when this call is commented out the second printf in crawler_init prints out the expected absolute url.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `buf->data = NULL;` fixes this:

```
#include <wget.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mysql.h>

MYSQL *mysql_con;

void
mysql_stop()
{
        mysql_close(mysql_con);
}

void
mysql_start()
{
        mysql_con = mysql_init(NULL);
        if (mysql_con == NULL)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(mysql_con));
                exit(1);
        }
        if (mysql_real_connect(mysql_con, "localhost", "crawler", "1q2w3e4r", "crawl", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(mysql_con));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}

const char * parseURI (char *base_url, char *url)
{
    wget_iri *base = wget_iri_parse(base_url, NULL);
    wget_buffer *buf = wget_buffer_alloc(8192);
    const char *uri = wget_iri_relative_to_abs(base, url, strlen(url), buf);
    buf->data = NULL;
    wget_buffer_free(&buf);
    wget_iri_free(&base);
    return uri;
}

void crawler_init()
{
    const char *url2 = parseURI("http://www.google.com/", "/intl/en/policies/privacy/");
    printf("%s\n", url2);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *url2 = parseURI("http://www.google.com/", "/intl/en/policies/privacy/");
    printf("%s\n", url2);
    mysql_start();
    crawler_init();
    mysql_stop();
}
```